# call to apache from varnish before serving cached content to user

Tags: apache, varnish

I have implemented varnish for my web pages.
 Now, I have one doubt can i call to Apache server before serving cached content to user 
 in this case, request flow will be varnish -> nginx ->apache

OR

can i serve varnish from apache level. in this case, request  flow will be

nginx -> apache ->varnish

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up any way you want. All depends on your particular requirements.

Typically you would want:

`Nginx (for SSL) -> Varnish (caching) -> Apache (for .htaccess)`

Comment: Actually my question is, can i call to apache server before serving cache content to user from varnish???

Comment: You can put Apache in front of Varnish, but Varnish has to fetch content from somewhere (another Apache or Nginx instance).